Datatables instance not synced with DOM (input checkbox status)
I have a table my_tbl initialized with datatables2.1.8.js jQuery library:
/* using python django template because table template is not in the same html file */
{% include 'my_tbl_template.html' %}  

let my_tbl=$('#my_tbl').DataTable({...}),

each cell containing
<input type="checkbox" value="some_value"> whether initially checked or unchecked;
The problem exactly is that my_tbl is not synced with the html dom after changing manually the checkboxes status! (check or uncheck);
e.g. when I have two checkboxes (2 cells) initially both checked, when user unchecks one of them
printCheckboxStatusDom() prints 1 //(expected number of checked checkboxes)
but
printCheckboxStatusTbl() prints 2 //the initial checked checkboxes
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        printCheckboxStatusDom();  // prints correctly how many checkbox is checked at this time
        printCheckboxStatusTbl(); //always prints initialized values (no change)
});



function printCheckboxStatusDom(){
    let checkeds = $(document).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
    console.log('DOM: checked boxes: ' + checkeds.length);
}



/* Function to print checkboxes status in the my_tbl instance */
function printCheckboxStatusTbl() {
    my_tbl.rows().every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
        let rowNode = this.node();
        let cellCheckboxes = $(rowNode).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
        console.log('Tbl: checked boxes: ' + cellCheckboxes.length);

         }
     );
 }


The problem was with DataTables initialization hierarchy in html page! my functions printCheckboxStatusDom(), printCheckboxStatusTbl() and $(document).ready(function(){...}) was in an my_scripts.js in a file and the html page was like
{% include 'my_tbl_template.html' %};<script>let my_tbl=$('#my_tbl').DataTable({...})</script><script type="text/javascript" src="my_scripts.js">
change to:
{% include 'my_tbl_template.html' %}<script type="text/javascript" src="my_scripts.js"><script>let my_tbl=$('#my_tbl').DataTable({...})</script>
solved!

apparantly initialization of datatable should be at the end!

You can answer your own question, if you know the answer. An answer in a comment is difficult to read.

Ok! KIKO Software

The problem was with DataTables initialization hierarchy in html page! my functions printCheckboxStatusDom(), printCheckboxStatusTbl() and $(document).ready(function(){...}) was stored in a javascript file my_scripts.js in a local dir, and the current page was like
    {% include 'my_tbl_template.html' %};
    <script>let my_tbl=$('#my_tbl').DataTable({...})</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="my_scripts.js">

so I tried to to change the code to (init datatables at the end):
    {% include 'my_tbl_template.html' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="my_scripts.js">
    <script>let my_tbl=$('#my_tbl').DataTable({...})</script>

And the problem solved!


The problem exactly is that my_tbl is not synced with the html dom after changing manually the checkboxes status! (check or uncheck)

Based on the code you're showing in the question, this is because you aren't updating the table when the DOM updates. DataTables doesn't do this automatically, you need to handle that using JS events - either by inserting/updating the table or just recreating it.
How you can/should do it depends on how you initialize the table to begin with, but here's a naíve approach that presupposes it's possible to repeat the original initialization logic.
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
        // When a checkbox is toggled, re-create the table
        let my_tbl=$('#my_tbl').DataTable({...}),
    });
});

It'll very likely be faster to update the table instead of recreating it every time, but the details of that depends on what your HTML looks like (i.e. will probably require identifiers on each checkbox element).

This is exactly what I suggested in the staging ground, but somehow it doesn't seem to be the problem. I didn't understand the comment however. Maybe you do?

I think OP is assuming that the existing solution they're using is correctly updating the table. But I think that assumption must be incorrect. This is assuredly not a problem with django or python, since this is client-side behavior. It's also not a HTML problem, since the DOM reportedly updates correctly. In my estimation, that only leaves the datatable as a possible culprit.

I agree. Let's see what Bill Choi thinks of this.

recreating Datatable instance produces recreation error! I have multiple dynamic Datatables in different pages but no recreating needed, just using .draw() method updates as just KIKO Software appointed but still the disaster remains...

I agree with you Vegard that this error is related to my Datatable initialization or updating process, I mentioned django template for further explanation if needed.

Without knowing what the error is, my first assumption is that you have to allow recreation by specifying the destroy attribute when the table is initialized.

And .draw() alone is probably not enough to update the table in a non-recreating fashion, you most likely need to use the .row() function and then look up the relevant row by a unique identifier (which you'll need to add to the DOM elements, i.e. data-id=somethingUnique)

might work, but the problem was solved by moving initialization line to the end, this shows datatables automatically updates with .draw()
